# How to install python without executable file on Windows?

Tags: installation

I am just starting with Python, and I need to install Python 3.8 version. I assume this is the right place to get it:
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3811/

After extracting .tar I get these files: [screenshot of folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtWEB.png) 
but I don't know what to do next.

I searched for the answer and then I tried installing it from command line, however - without success.
I would be grateful if you could help me with such a basic but essential issue.
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Read this [Using Python on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html)

Comment: Thank you for posting!
However I didn't find any straightforward solution there. I only found this clue (not sure if it is correct though):


"3.11. Compiling Python on Windows
If you want to compile CPython yourself, first thing you should do is get the source. (...)

The source tree contains a build solution and project files for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, which is the compiler used to build the official Python releases. These files are in the PCbuild directory. (...)"


Could it be that making "source tarball" work means we have to compile it?
Or am I mixing up something?